# itoa Integer to Ascii with varying radix

Tags: assembly, ascii, mips

Long time lurker, first time asker. I'm just starting out with MIPS and am a bit confused by a project. The assignment is to create a program which takes an integer input and outputs the ascii conversion for radix 2 through 16. I think, as shown below, that I have figured out the initial conversion but the radix loop still evades me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
.data
str:        .space  128     # space for the output string

    # examples of macros, for printing. 
    .macro print_int (%x)
    add $a0, $zero, %x
    li  $v0, 1
    syscall
    .end_macro

    .macro print_str (%x)
    la  $a0, %x
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall
    .end_macro

    # str address is in a register
    .macro print_str_r (%x)
    add $a0, $zero, %x
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall
    .end_macro

    .text           # Code segment
    .globl  main        # declare main to be global

main:       
    print_str(name)     # use macro 

    # You can read the number with a system call
    #li $s0, 49
    #li $v0, 5      #read an integer
    #syscall
    #move   $s0, $v0    #save the user input

    li  $s0, 0xFFFFFFFF # pseudo instruction for loading large constant
    la  $s1, str

    # You need to construct a loop to use radices 2 .. 16
    # for $s2 = 2, $s2 < 17, $s2 ++
    li  $s2, 2

    #call itoa
    move    $a0, $s0    #save n to $s0
    move    $a1, $s1    
    move    $a2, $s2
    jal     itoa

    # print the radix
    print_int($s2)      # note $a0 and $v0 are overwritten 
    print_str(msg_tab)
    print_str_r($s1)
    print_str(msg_nl)

    # Need to jump back to the beginning of the loop

Exit:   li  $v0,10      # System call, type 10, standard exit
    syscall         # ...and call the OS


# function itoa (value, buffer, radix)
# it only returns '0' for now.
# you can return an empty string '' if the radix is not supported.
itoa:
     addi $t0,$zero,10 # t0=10
     addi $t1,$t1,a0   # t1=a0
     Loop:
          div $t1,$t0    #t1/10
          mflo $t1      #t1 = quotient
          mfhi $t2      #t2 =remainder
          addi $t2,$t2,0x30 #Convert to ASCII
          addi $sp,$sp,-1 #Make space for 1 byte in the stack
          sb $t2,0($sp) #Push t2 in the stack
          addi $v0,$v0,1 #v0=v0+1
          bne $t1,$zero,Loop #If t1<>0 go to Loop
     order:
              sw $t0,$v0  #t0=v0
          lb $t1,0($sp) #pop the last byte for the stack
          addi $sp,$sp,1 #Reduce the stack size by 1 byte
          add $t2,$v0,-$t0 #t2=v0-t0
          sb $t1,$t2($a1) # savebyte to the proper location of memory
          addi $t0,$t0,-1 #t0=t0-1
          bne $to,$zero,order #If t0<>0 go to order
     sb 0x0,$v($a0) # add null character to the end of the string
     jr $ra
```

EDIT:
Here is some C code I have which I just need to translate but am unsure how to make the loop for Radix to work

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>

char    * my_itoa(unsigned int  v, char *p, int r)
{
    unsigned int c;
    char    *p_old, *q;
    static char   hexdigits[32] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    if (r < 2 || r > 16) {
        *p = 0;
        return p;
    }

    if (v == 0) {       // return '0'
        p[0] = '0'; 
        p[1] = 0;   // end of the string.
        return p;
    }

    p_old = p;      // save the starting address of the buffer

    // doing the conversion
    // p points to the location where to store the next character
    while (v > 0) {
        // You can get both c an v with ONE MIPS instruction 
        c = v % r;
        v = v / r;
        *p = hexdigits[c];
        p ++; // increment p 
    }

    *p = 0;     // end of the string

    // reverse the string

    // q points to the head and p points to the tail
    q = p_old;
    p = p - 1;

    while (q < p) {
        // swap *q and *p
        c = *q;
        *q = *p;
        *p = c;

        // increment q and decrement p
        q ++;
        p --;
    }

    return p_old;
}

char    buf[128];

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int r;
    unsigned int n = (argc > 1) ? atoi(argv[1]) : (unsigned int)-1; 

    for (r = 2; r <= 16; r ++) 
        printf("r=%d\t%s\n", r, my_itoa(n, buf, r));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to loop in assembler:

```
define_some_loop_label_at_first_instruction_of_loop:
    ; first instruction of loop
    ; ... other part of loop (can also send execution completely elsewhere)
    ; but should return back into loop (or you need to have duplicate loop test)

    ; end of loop, do the "loop test"
    ; (here you also may want to do things like increment loop counter, etc)

    ; calculate the loop-exit expressions, if not true
    ; jump to define_some_loop_label_at_first_instruction_of_loop
```

In your case it looks like you have radix value in `$s2`.
The comment says:

```
# for $s2 = 2, $s2 < 17, $s2 ++
```

Which is correct, but not exact, you want to loop till $s2 <= 16.
So it should be like:

```
    load s2 with 2
radix_loop:
    ... do the stuff (s2 contains radix value)
    ++s2
    test s2 against 16
    when less or equal, jump to radix_loop
    ; on MIPS the test + jump can be single (pseudo) instruction
    ; similar to the "bne $t1,$zero,Loop" in your other code

    ; here radix is 17 -> continue with any "exit" code you wish
```

---

BTW, did you type that asm source into question by hand, or how can this happen:

```
    bne $to,$zero,order #If t0<>0 go to order
```

(`$to` instead of `$t0`)

You should just copy the source from the actual source, so anyone trying to answer your question can repeat your steps and get to the same problem. This one probably can't even compile?